# Azure Dasboards alert based on percentage

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-log-analytics, appinsights

In Azure dashboards, is there any way we can trigger alerts based on percentage instead of counts?.. Example if total  total failures in 20 minutes is 20%, then trigger alert than just cheking the counts of the failures? Here setting the count is not meeting our requirement and looking a solution based on the Percentage of occurance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the above shared requirement , we have created the custom Kusto query to calculate the percentage of failure requests & to trigger an email alert notification if the failure requests percentage > 20% for a particular web app & also projecting the output of the Kusto query to the dashboard as well.

Here is the custom Kusto query :

```
requests
| where timestamp >= ago(6h)
| project success, ['id'], resultCode, appName
| summarize failedtotal = countif(success == 'False'), total= count()
| project  failurepercentage = (100 * (failedtotal) / (total))
| summarize totalouputrows=countif(failurepercentage>20) by failurepercentage
```

Use the New alert rule option in the log analytics space to create a custom alert & using the above query as signal as shown in below picture.

[image]

Use the Pin to dashboard option in the log analytics work space to project the output of the custom Kusto query & create the dashboard accordingly.

[image]

Here is the sample image of the alert rule that was created using the above query.

[image]

Here is the sample email output & Kusto query output projected to dashboard triggered by above alert rule.

[image]

Comment: need some clarification on the last part of the query.. Because in my scenario I used below query to get the percentage.

Comment: AppDependencies
|where AppRoleName == "my-app"
| Data contains "myname"
| summarize failedtotal = countif(Success == 'False'), total= count()
| project  failurepercentage = (100 * (failedtotal) / (total))
| summarize totalouputrows=countif(failurepercentage>0) by failurepercentage

Comment: the total request received was 23415, where failed was 276. so that about 1.1%, and resulted the failure percentaage as 1% ( not sure why its excluded the decimal value)

Comment: so here , whats the totalouputrows stands for, and i got again  1 as output when i put the failrepercentage >0,